# Pegar valor do option (HTML) de acordo com o Radio Buttom escolhido

Tags: php

Estou tentando realizar a seguinte operação.

Tenho dois tipos Radio Buttom, e um Select html para cada um desses Radios.

Sendo que quando eu marco por exemplo o radio "informatica" e  aparece o as opções sobre informática, e vou enviar o formulario, no banco está salvando o valor que está no option do segundo radio (no caso manutenção)

Se eu remover o rádio manutenção e  tentar enviar o formulário, funciona e envia os itens de informática.

Não consegui entender qual o erro, ou o que estou deixando passar despercebido

estou tentando pegar os valores com PHP $_POST[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido da seguinte forma:

Para cada Select/Option eu coloquei um nome.
Peguei o valor do Rádio que estava marcado no momento em que o usuário enviou o formulário.
Depois criei uma condição na página que recebe os dados do formulário, que verifica quais os dados que estão sendo passados via POST, no caso se o usuário marcou o rádio 'informática', a condição executa os inserts relacionados a categoria informática.

Enfim, não ficou algo cem por cento limpo, mas no momento está funcional.